# Object chang size(android)

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, imageview, size

Sorry for my English. I have a dynamically created TextView and ImageView, they are added to the LinearLayout. But when I start to write a TextView that it changes its size and thus reduces the ImageView. The picture below is an example of how the size of the

[image]

```
 final LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
             row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
             row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

             //params editTExt
             android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsEtext = new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
             paramsEtext.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

             //params image View
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsImageView = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.25f);
             paramsImageView.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;

             //create edit text
             final EditText etext = new EditText(QuicklyCreateQwestions.this);
             etext.setLayoutParams(paramsEtext);

             //add et in ArrayList
             et.add(etext);

             //set text in textView
             etext.setText(qwestions.get(i).toString());
             row.addView(etext);

             //add ImageView in edit text
             final ImageView imV = new ImageView(this);
             imV.setLayoutParams(paramsImageView);
             imV.setImageResource(R.drawable.t_del_poll);
             imV.setId(i);

             //set button in layaut
             row.addView(imV);

             //action if button click
             imV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        row.removeView(etext);
                        row.removeView(imV);
                    }
                }); 

             //add editText and button in layaut
             LinearLayoutTextQwestions.addView(row);
```

Comment: Well... you set it to wrap_content, when the content gets bigger it also gets bigger. Try setting it to a fixed width.